# Rather than you doing -- omit pronoun?

Tags: comparative-constructions

1. > I'd prefer to do it myself rather than you doing.
2. > I'd prefer to do it myself rather than that you do.
3. > I'd prefer to do it myself rather than that you did.

Is using a pronoun after the phrase ''rather than'' (as in the first example) proper? Which one of them would be grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

None of the three are perfect, but the first example is the closest. The only problem is that it's missing word: "it".

The grammatically correct version would be:

> I'd prefer to do it myself rather than you doing it.

This is the only example where the verbs match in future tense. The other two mix tenses.